# How can I arrange content blocks like pinterest?

Tags: html, css

http://pinterest.com/ have a intresting structures of blocks. How I can make the same?

Now I have this code:
`li {`
`float:left;`
`margin-right:10px;`
`}`

And I get this result:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/339/49022374.png

But, I need this:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/197/86816998.png

Comment: Stack Overflow is best suited for asking practical, specific questions. Typically it would be appreciated if you include some code (tell us what you've tried so far) in the question (note that you can edit the question).

Comment: They do it by absolutely positioning the blocks, and then computing and writing the `top`, and `left` values via JavaScript. The [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) jQuery plug-in provides this functionality.

Comment: Maybe I can do it in the other way, without JS?

Answer (score 1):

Why involving JS?

All you need is a number of floated column divs with inner divs

here is a simple [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M34e2/)

HTML

```
<div class="col">
   <div>
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam porta arcu quis risus ultricies viverra ac at velitmentum vestibulum. Aenean faucibus nunc sed quam vehicula laoreet. Aliquam
</div>
<div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam porta arcu quis risus ultricies viverra ac at velit. Morbi congue, tellus a faucibus euismod, velit ante sagittis ligula, et sagitti</div>
<div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam porta arcu quis risus ultricies viverra ac at velit. Morbi congue, tellus a faucibus euismod, velit ante sagitti
</div>
</div>
<div class="col">
    <div>
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam porta arcu quis risus ultricies viverra ac at velit. Morbi congue, tellus a faucibus euismod, velit ante sagittis ligula, et sagittis nibh nulla eget purus. Nunc nec tellus massa. Cras sit amet tortor nec libero condimentum vestibulum. Aenean faucibus nunc sed quam vehicula laoreet. Aliquam
</div>
<div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam porta arcu quis risus ultricies viverra ac at velit. Morbi congue, tellus a faucibus euismod, velit ante sagittis ligula, et sagitti</div>
<div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam porta arcu quis risus ultricies viverra ac at velit. Morbi congue, tellus a faucibus euismod, velit ante sagittis ligula, et sagittis nibh nulla eget purus. Nunc nec tellus massa. Cras sit amet tortor nec libero condimentum vestibulum. Aenean faucibus nunc sed quam vehicula laoreet. Aliquam
</div>
</div>
<div class="col">
    <div>
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam porta arcu quis risus ultricies viverra ac at velit. Morbi congue, tellus a faucibus euismod, velit ante 
</div>
<div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam porta arcu quis risus ultricies viverra ac at velit. Morbi congue, tellus a faucibus euismod, velit ante sagittis ligula, et sagitti</div>
<div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam porta arcu quis risus ultricies viverra ac at velit. Morbi congue, tellus a faucibus euismod, velit ante sagittis l
</div>
</div>
<div class="col">
    <div>
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam porta arcu quis risus ultricies viverra ac at velit. Morbi congue, tellus a faucibus euismod, velit ant
</div>
<div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam porta arcu quis risus ultricies viverra ac at velit. Morbi congue, tellus a faucibus euismod, velit ante sagittis ligula, et sagitti</div>
<div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam porta arcu quis risus ultricies viverra ac at velit. Morbi congue, tellus a faucibus euismod, velit ante sagittis li
</div>
</div>
```

​
CSS

```
.col {
width:20%;
    float:left;

}
.col div {
margin:10px;
    padding:5px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
​
```